# How to cast child class instance

Tags: java, casting

I don't really know exactly how to word this but basically I need to get the child class instance of an Actor without assigning it (if that makes since?).  Is this possible?

```
package org.game.world.entity.actor;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.game.world.entity.Entity;
import org.game.world.entity.actor.npc.NPC;
import org.game.world.entity.actor.player.Player;
import org.game.world.entity.actor.player.PlayerData;

public abstract class Actor extends Entity {

    /**
     * The type of Actor this Entity should be
     * recognized as.
     */
    private final ActorType actorType;

    /**
     * A map of ActionStates, not necessarily 'Attributes'.
     */
    private final Map<ActionState, Boolean> actionState = new HashMap<ActionState, Boolean>();

    /**
     * Constructs a new Actor {@Entity}.
     */
    public Actor(ActorType actorType) {
        this.actorType = actorType;
        actionState.putAll(ActionState.DEFAULT_ACTION_STATES);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the status of a {@Actor} ActionSate.
     * @param state The ActionState.
     * @return The ActionState flag.
     */
    public boolean getActionState(ActionState state) {
        return actionState.get(state);
    }

    /**
     * Sets a {@Actor} ActionState flag.
     * @param state The ActionState.
     * @param flag The flag true:false.
     */
    public void setActionState(ActionState state, boolean flag) {
        actionState.put(state, flag);
    }

    /**
     * Resets all ActionState's for this Actor.
     */
    public void setDefaultActionStates() {
        actionState.putAll(ActionState.DEFAULT_ACTION_STATES);
    }

    /**
     * Checks if this Actor is a specific ActorType (i.e NPC)
     * @param actorType The ActorType
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isActorType(ActorType actorType) {
        return this.actorType == actorType;
    }

    /**
     * The type of Actor.
     */
    public static enum ActorType {
        PLAYER,
        NPC
    }

}
```

An Actor type.

```
package org.game.world.entity.actor.player;

import org.game.world.entity.Location;
import org.game.world.entity.actor.Actor;
import org.game.world.entity.actor.SkillLink;

/**
 * This class represents a Player {@Actor} in the world.
 * 
 * @author dillusion
 *
 */
public class Player extends Actor {

    /**
     * This Player objects unique set of stored
     * data.
     */
    private final PlayerData playerData;

    /**
     * Creates a new Player object in the world.
     * @param playerData The set of data unique to this Player.
     */
    public Player(PlayerData playerData) {
        super(ActorType.PLAYER);
        this.playerData = playerData;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the players name.
     * @return The name.
     */
    public String getName() {
        return playerData.name;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the players password.
     * @return The password.
     */
    public String getPassword() {
        return playerData.password;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the players permission level.
     * @return The permission.
     */
    public Permission getPermission() {
        return playerData.permission;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the players SkillLink instance.
     * @return The SkillLink.
     */
    public SkillLink getSkillLink() {
        return playerData.skillLink;
    }

    @Override
    public Location getLocation() {
        return playerData.location;
    }

    @Override
    public Location setLocation(Location location) {
        return playerData.location = location;
    }

}
```

But let's say I have multiple 'Actors'.  I don't want to have to cast if I don't need to.

Sorry if I didn't explain this very well.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what are you questioning about here - so what i have figured out that you might want to do is to use Player as Actor right? Well that is possible by Java standard and inheritance

```
Actor temp=new Actor(){//implementing abstract methods if any}
Actor player=new Player(); //that is still fine as Actor is common superclas for player and actor

Player another=(Player)player; // thats just fine after typecasting
////but
another=player; // compile error, type mismatch 
another=(Player)temp; // ClassCastException but no compilation error;
```

But still you can use different Actors and Players as Actors.

Comment: Can you please explain what do you understand by "child instance" ?

Comment: How could I cast appropriately to either NPC or Player based on the ActorType.  Both NPC and Player actors contain unique data to that type of actor, so what I'm asking is if I have an attacker and a defender, one is a Player actor the other is a NPC actor how can I differentiate the two and get the appropriate cast?

Comment: 1) Use both Actors as Actors and put data in actor class OR you can always check with `insanceof` what type your instance is.

Comment: Besides whole point of inheritance is to put common things in one class and differences in another ones that inherits from the common one, so my suggestion is - take the path, where every NPC Player etc. has one supperclass and thread all of these instances as superclass type.